# How to find the bar which is the highest high green bar within 5 bars, excluding the current bar?

Tags: charts, pine-script, trading, indicator, pine-script-v4

I would like to find the green bar which is the highest high bar of last 5 bars, and not the current bar (the current bar may be the highest green one, so I need to exclude it)

I tried this but it seems not correct

```
find = high == highest(high, 5) and close > open and bar_index > 0 and bar_index < 6
numb = barssince(find)
high_of_that_bar = high[numb]
low_of_that_bar = low[numb])
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

i_bars = input.int(5, "Bars back")

var float   green_hi    = 0
var float   green_lo    = 0
var label   lbl         = label.new(na, na, "")

if barstate.islast
    green_hi := 0
    for i = 1 to i_bars
        if close[i] > open[i] and high[i] > green_hi
            green_hi := high[i]
            green_lo := low[i]

    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index+1, high)
    label.set_text(lbl, str.format("green within last {2} bars\nhigh = {0}\nlow = {1}", green_hi, green_lo, i_bars))
```

This shows the fractional bar-index for intraday timeframes

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

i_bars = input.int(5, "Bars back")

var float   green_hi    = 0
var float   green_lo    = 0
var label   lbl         = label.new(na, na, "")
var int     mybarindex  = na
var int     mybar       = na
var int     myi         = na

if barstate.islast
    green_hi := 0
    for i = 1 to i_bars
        if close[i] > open[i] and high[i] > green_hi
            green_hi := high[i]
            green_lo := low[i]
            mybarindex := bar_index
            mybar := bar_index - i
            myi := i

    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index+1, high)
    label.set_text(lbl, str.format("green within last {2} bars\nhigh = {0,number,#.#######}\nlow = {1,number,#.#######}\nmybar = {3}\nmybarindex = {4}\nmyi = {5}", green_hi, green_lo, i_bars, mybar, mybarindex, myi))
```

I got a second opinion, and it seems `bar_index` is not fractional after all.
`str.format()` just separates thousands with commas.

This makes it clear:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

i_bars = input.int(5, "Bars back")

var float   green_hi    = 0
var float   green_lo    = 0
var label   lbl         = label.new(na, na, "")
var int     mybarindex  = na
var int     mybar       = na
var int     myi         = na

if barstate.islast
    green_hi := 0
    for i = 1 to i_bars
        if close[i] > open[i] and high[i] > green_hi
            green_hi := high[i]
            green_lo := low[i]
            mybarindex := bar_index
            mybar := bar_index - i
            myi := i

    label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index+1, high)
    label.set_text(lbl, str.format("green within last {2} bars\nhigh = {0,number,#.#######}\nlow = {1,number,#.#######}\nmybar = {3}\nmybarindex = {4}\nmyi = {5}", green_hi, green_lo, i_bars, mybar, mybarindex, myi))

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index - 10, high, str.format("{0}", bar_index + 0.1))
```

Comment: How do I know the bar_index of that bar? For example, it's the high[3]. So I can check other things of that bar, ie. the top[3] / middle[3] / bottom[3] lines of the Bollinger Bands at that bar. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: The calculation happens on the last bar, so the `bar_index` you're looking for is `bar_index - i`

Comment: It does work, but it's just rounded because the values are so small. Please change the label code line to this to show all 7 digits : `label.set_text(lbl, str.format("green within last {2} bars\nhigh = {0,number,#.#######}\nlow = {1,number,#.#######}", green_hi, green_lo, i_bars))`

Comment: I changed it. It works. It shows the correct value now. But for the bar_index - i, it shows a float value 3,566 for the chart UNFIBTC, but the bar_index should be an integer value, and it should be 1, not 3 because the highest high bar of UNFIBTC timeframe 4H (6-Jul-2022) is just the last bar. Did I miss something?

Comment: Aha, you're right. It seems that bar_index is fractional for intraday timeframes. I didn't know that. That's weird, because it's defined as an `int` in the [bar_index](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_bar_index) definition. I added code to my answer to show that.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a great person. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Added "not fractional after all" segment to my answer. It's just the way `str.format()` works by separating thousands with a comma, which gives the illusion that it's fractional. Thousand separator = comma and decimal separator = dot